# Error while sorting products in category

Tags: magento2

I'm facing following error when I try set sort for the products in category :
" Something went wrong while saving the category. "

Notice: getimagesize(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in /home/MY_DOMAIN/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File/Mime.php on line 115

Could you please advise.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? The code is trying to open a 'directory' 
instead of a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542374/error-file-get-contents-read-of-8192-bytes-failed-with-errno-21

Comment: Hi Dear, Yes I'm using custom theme, I've checked link but I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Your theme seems to be trying to open a file, but the given path is a directory (more than likely the file name is empty)

Comment: Okay, how I can solve it ?